# Flake8 in molecule3

Tags: ansible, flake8, molecule

after upgrading to molecule3 i've changed to new way of defining lints:

```
lint: |
  yamllint -d "{ignore: env}" .
  ansible-lint
  flake8
```

It works for yamllint and ansible-lint, but it fails for flake8, in enters to console of flake8 and stays there.

```
molecule 3.0.2
   ansible==2.9.4 python==3.6
```

Thanks

Comment: there is no console mode of flake8 I am aware of. Run with —debug.

Comment: I suspect it's recursing through your virtualenv and linting every file there and it's taking a very long time

Comment: Yes, could be that flake8 is scanning  all files. Tnx I will add some exceptions